# I can't seem to get replaceAll to work (remove all content between two strings)

Tags: java, android, regex, replaceall

So I am trying to remove all the content between two strings (including the two strings) and I can't figure out why my code is not working. I even tested it on this website: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

And their "replaceAll()" section has the exact string I'm expecting, but what I get on my Android app is the entire original string with no changes. I have tried different methods based on examples found on this site such as:

```
String thematch = Pattern.quote("<p>Listen") + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote("</audio></p>");
String thenew = thecontent.replaceAll(thematch, "");
```

And:

```
String thenew = thecontent.replaceAll("<p>Listen(.*?)</audio></p>","");
```

Neither are replacing the string. What's going on?

Edit: Fixed by adding (?s) to the beginning of thematch as anubhava said.

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. Perhaps you should show what input string it does not work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `s` flag (DOTALL) that lets you match `.` newlines also:

```
String thematch = "(?s)" + Pattern.quote("<p>Listen") + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote("</audio></p>");
```

However as a word of caution you should use a HTML/XML parser for manipulating HTML documents.

Comment: There are no new lines in the HTML source; I still tried your version anyway and it didn't work.

Comment: Try updated code.. I had `(?s)` inside `quote` method.